# Ruby - infer if something is time-date like

Tags: ruby

Attempting to infer whether or not a `thing` is a date/time like thing.

When plagued with rails, you can get objects where `thing.class` can be

```
Time
Date
DateTime
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
_probably other stuff I never heard of_
```

I *could* just do

```
thing.class.then{|x| [Date, Time, DateTime, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone].include?(x)}
```

But this list is finite, what if there is a new class which is introduced? It would quietly do unintended behaviour, a bug buried deeply in a library nobody would think to look at.

I want to be able to infer whether a value is time-like without having to compare its class to a list of known (so far) date/time types, if possible. So far I have

```
thing.class.ancestors.map(&:to_s).join(',').then{|x| x.include?('Date') || x.include?('Time')}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm apprehensive about prodding with `respond_to?` *quack quack* with methods a date-time kind of thing might use.

Comment: What do you need this detection for? What is it that you want to do with any "date-time-like" object? (especially given your concern about new classes of this "type").

Comment: I personally would probably go with comparing against a list of known classes. If a new thing appears, chances are that my program can't deal with it anyway and has to be changed.

Comment: I second what @SergioTulentsev says - "inconvenience" coming from the need to maintain a list of classes is nothing compared to a risk to treat as date something that is not. Maintenance-wise it is a one-line change in a well-known place vs potentially tricky debugging...

Comment: _"what if there is a new class which is introduced? It would quietly do unintended behaviour"_ – it would behave just like before, handling the objects that it knows. It seems much more likely to get unintended behavior if you interact with objects of unknown type.

Comment: What is "date/time like"? Couldn't you just go with `thing.class <= Time || thing.class <= Date`?

Comment: When `thing.class == ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is true, the `thing.class <= Time || thing.class <= Date` returns `nil`. Thanks for the comments everyone, I'll use the finite list approach

Comment: @xxjjnn you could try switching to `is_a?` according to the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) when When `thing.class == ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone #=> true` then also `thing.is_a?(Time) #=> true` so `thing.is_a?(Time) || thing.is_a?(Date)` should work.

Comment: Rails adds `to_datetime` methods to a lot of these, which is a hint. Ruby itself, no such convenience.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

The right way to think about this is to solve for your intermediate storage format, rather than worrying about the "type" of the object that generates the initial Date or Time values. If you're focusing on types rather than values or common methods, you're not leveraging idiomatic Ruby.

### Focus on Intermediate Storage or Interchange Formats

Ruby is a highly dynamic language, so "types" aren't really a thing. Even if you use YARD tags to document an interface, or RBS to document your interfaces, Ruby itself simply doesn't enforce contracts between the caller and callee, and other than ultimately descending from Object or BasicObject you can't accurately infer anything about "types" even from the ancestry chain because all objects can be reopened or modified with mixins or singletons.

If you don't want to do duck-typing, then you need to work with a common serializer or intermediate format that is supported by all the objects you care about. For example, you could convert a Time, Date, DateTime or other similar object to a collection of seconds since epoch, and rely on a known class to parse the seconds back into a suitable format when you need to use it.

Consider the following:

```rb
# Just for your reference.
UNIX_EPOCH = Time.at 18_000

# Use an array as a container for your storing your data
# in a common format.
@seconds_since_epoch = []

# Take any time-like object that can be coerced to a String
# and parsed by Time#parse without raising exceptions.
#
# @param str [String, #String, #to_str, #to_s] a String or
#   Kernel#String coercible type parseable by Time#parse
# @return [Array<Integer>] collection of time values in
#   seconds since the epoch
def convert_datelike_to_epoch str
  @seconds_since_epoch << Time.parse(String(str)).to_i
end

[Time.now, Date.today, DateTime.now]
  .map { convert_datelike_to_epoch _1 } &&
  @seconds_since_epoch
#=> [1659158765, 1659153600, 1659158765]
```

You can do whatever you want with the values stored in *@seconds_since_epoch* this way. At least they'll be in a consistent format. You can then parse them back out with anything you like, including [Time#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime), [Time#parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse), [DateTime#strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), or any other tool of your choice.

Note that this doesn't really require you to know much about the time- or date-generating objects involved as long as they have sensible internal String representations. It will also prevent unexpected values from being added to your Array by raising an exception if it can't coerce the input value to a String or parse it as a date. For example:

```rb
convert_datelike_to_epoch "ABCD"
#=> no time information in "ABCD" (ArgumentError)

convert_datelike_to_epoch 0.1
#=> no time information in "0.1" (ArgumentError)
```